# SQL works fine until I add a SUBSTR to subquery, then it just hangs. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables, call them t1 and t2. Both have column names str_id. The  str_id is typically a 10 digit string, but I have special str_ids that begin with 'sp' followed by a normal 10 digit str_id. I would like to select all the 'sp' str_ids from t1, remove the sp, and look up the str_id in t2. I tried this query:

```
Select
    str_id,
    desired_column
From
    t2 
Where
    str_id in (
        Select
            substr(str_id, 3)
        From
            t1
        Where
            str_id Like 'sp%' and
            other_column = 'my_value'
    );
```

Syntactically, this command seems correct, but when I run it my SQL frontend just hangs. If I run the command without the SUBSTR, then it executes fine, but it doesn't return the results I want because all the str_ids have sp prefixed. Just for reference, the command that works is:

```
Select
    str_id, 
    desired_column 
From
    t2 
Where
    str_id In (
        Select
            str_id 
        From
            t1 
        Where
            str_id Like 'sp%' and 
            other_column = 'my_value'
    );
```

What can I do to fix the query above?

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT SUBSTR(str_id, 3) FROM t1 WHERE str_id LIKE 'sp%' and other_column = 'my_value'` from the command line?

Comment: I get a list of str_ids with the sp removed.

Comment: Some example data with desired results would make this much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the `EXPLAIN` outputs of those two, but I assume with the normal one mysql is able to directy crossreference indexes, while the `SUBSTR` one requires creating an intermediate resultset, and checking each individual item from t2. Which is a nice example why prefixing values with significant data is about as bad as people storing delimited strings in 1 column: hard to work with.

Comment: Thank you. This was actually the problem. Once I gave aliases to the intermediate result set everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer. Try running this instead

```
SELECT str_id,
(
SELECT desired_column
FROM t2
WHERE str_id = SUBSTR(t1.str_id, 3)
)
FROM t1
WHERE str_id LIKE 'sp%' AND other_column = 'my_value'
```

Comment: That does not work. It returns the same result as if the SUBSTR was not used at all.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're saying that `t2.str_id` values do not contain the 'sp' prefix, while `t1.str_id` do? You may want to rethink your data model. I suspect that there is an index on `t1.str_id` that cannot be used when you are trying to match `subst(t1.str_id,3)` to `t2.str_id`.

Depending on the relative sizes of the tables, this may perform faster:

```
SELECT 
 str_id, desired_column 
FROM 
 t2 
WHERE 
 concat( 'sp' , str_id ) IN (
    SELECT str_id FROM t1 
    WHERE str_id LIKE 'sp%' and other_column = 'my_value'
 );
```